# How can I set up Haskell's GHCI to interactively evaluate functions to their signature (type) instead of getting errors?

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, ghci

To see the function's signature in Haskell GHCI, I have to prefix it with `:t`:

```
Prelude> f = \x -> x+1
Prelude> :t f
f :: Num a => a -> a
```

But typing that prefix every time grows quickly old. If I leave it out, I get error:

```
Prelude> f

<interactive>:5:1: error:
• No instance for (Show (a0 -> a0)) arising from a use of ‘print’
    (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
• In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘it’
  In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Instead of getting this error message, I would like see some useful information about my function `f` similar to the one I get with `:t f` (possibly even more information about `f`).

How can I set up the GHCI to achieve this functionality, i.e. getting function's info upon entering it without `:t`?

Comment: Non-answers: the `:i` command show some extra information about a value beyond its type; it also works with classes (however, it is a prefix command just like `:t`). Also, `:set +t` will make GHCi print the type of anything that is successfully evaluated at the command prompt (however, it unfortunately doesn't help with the no-instance-for-Show situation you talk about).

Comment: I think you should rephrase the question in a way that doesn't put down GHCi. What you want seems fairly reasonable; people are likely to be more interested in helping if you ask nicely.

Comment: Well the error message should clue you in to how the repl works. I don't think what you want is possible. It might be a good idea though. Or it might be an arbitrary special case that would confuse people.

Comment: @jberryman, I think a variation on it probably is possible, although I think it should be controlled by an option. The OP's request doesn't really sound like a great default to me.

Comment: Also a non-answer, but perhaps an amusing one: `instance (Typeable a, Typeable b) => Show (a -> b) where show = show . typeOf`. But beware the polymorphic function.

Comment: @dfeuer Point taken, removed that part.

Comment: @jberryman I find the error messages very "cryptic" (I'm only learning it, so it may be just me).

Answer (score 4):

You probably can't do this today. I've opened [a feature request](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/13039#ticket) to see about adding options to control what GHCi reports about type errors at the prompt.

Comment: You mean I can't even reconfigure the function (`Show`?) that runs on `f` in that case?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev, you can configure what function is used to print values in GHCi, but that will not help you, unless I'm very confused about what you're after.

Comment: I am after printing `:t f` (before the error message) when typing `f`.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev, right, and you can't get that at the GHCi command line. You can get an awful lot using emacs or vim to interact with GHCi.

Answer (score 2):

GHCi will already happily show you the types of anything you type into the prompt, with the option `:set +t`. The only issue is that `show` is called on the thing, and there is no proper manner for showing functions - and the type is only printed for an expression which can be shown in a valid manner. However, you can get around this quite easily:

```
>newtype ShowType a = ShowType a
newtype ShowType a = ShowType a
>instance Show (ShowType a) where show _ = "The type is"
>:set +t
>ShowType const
The type is
it :: ShowType (a -> b -> a)
```

Unfortunately, this creates quite a lot of syntactic noise. My preferred solution is to add the following to the `.ghci` file:

```
:set +t 
instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} Show a where show _ = "The type is"
```

Adding such a `Show` instance to any real Haskell module would be a grave mistake, but within the `.ghci` module, it only scopes over expressions typed into the prompt, so it seems okay to me. With this, you get:

```
>const
The type is
it :: a -> b -> a
>show
The type is
it :: Show a => a -> String
```

Conveniently, when you have a function whose type is 'technically' valid but has unsatisfiable constraints, you still get a type error:

```
>:t \x -> x `div` (x / x)
\x -> x `div` (x / x) :: (Integral a, Fractional a) => a -> a
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

>\x -> x `div` (x / x)

<interactive>:12:1: error:
    * Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `it'
      prevents the constraint `(Fractional a0)' from being solved.
```

---

However, the absolute simplest solution is to `:set +t` and to give a `let` statement when your expression is non-`Show`able:

```
>let _f = show
_f :: Show a => a -> String
```

Unfortunately, if the left-hand side is the wildcard - `let _ = show` - then the type is not printed.